# how can I transform size of svg with svg-edit

Tags: svg-edit

Is it possible to change the size of an existing svg using svg edit? I https://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/ I have a rather large svg that I wish to scale down. Google's tool doesn't have an icon (that I can see) to scale the size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling an entire SVG document isn't really supported as a button press or anything but it can be accomplished.

Open your project into SVG-Edit, select everything (press A on your keyboard) then right click and choose Group. Then go to Menu > Document Properties and enter your new dimensions. Then select your SVG content and move it onto your new small canvas. Easiest way is to use the X and Y coordinates in the top grey bar (enter 0 for both). Then just resize the whole document as needed by dragging the small circles located on the corners of your content. Hold the shift key on your keyboard to scale proportionately.